# Disconnected response connecting aws lambda to rds

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-lex

I am trying to connect my lambda function to an rds so that I can query it on Amazon Lex but I cant seem to get the connection to the RDS. The vpc and security group portions have been settled because they do work on a simple function. Below is a sample of my code. ${connection.status} is returning disconnected. Would appreciate any help i can get thank you!

Just to be very clear, I actually defined a dispatch function at the top. The export handler takes place below. Edited the code to make it very clear.

```
function dispatch(intentRequest, callback) {
    const sessionAttributes = intentRequest.sessionAttributes;
    const slots = intentRequest.currentIntent.slots;
    const mysql = require('mysql');

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'xxx',
        user: 'admin',
        password: 'xxx',
        database: 'xxx',
        port: 3306
    });

    exports.handler = (event, context) => {
        connection.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                context.fail();
            } else {
                context.succeed('Success');
            }
        });
    };

    callback(close(sessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled', {
        'contentType': 'PlainText',
        'content': `Thank you ${connection.state}`
    }));
}

// Route the incoming request based on intent.
// The JSON body of the request is provided in the event slot.
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        dispatch(event, (response) => {
            callback(null, response);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the initialization of your RDS connection is asynchronous you need to move the logic inside the callback of `connection.connect`

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'xxx',
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'xxx',
    database: 'xxx',
    port: 3306
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, close(sessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled', {
                'contentType': 'PlainText',
                'content': `Thank you ${connection.state}`
            }));
        }
    });
};
```

Edit:
Please keep the order of the parameters in `callback` in mind. First argument is supposed to be an error and second is the response.

Comment: The error message shows that theres an unhandled error response.

Comment: thank you for your response. It shows that it received a null response from lambda.

Comment: Hi @MaiKaY thank you for your response. I edited the code above to make it clearer. I actually defined a dispatch function. Could you please see if that could be a potential issue? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe there might be some asynchronous processing happening, by using a callback in your `connection.connect` function it is likely hitting the Lambdas `callback` function before the `connection.connect` function triggers.

In addition keep the callback inside the `exports.handler`.

Try updating your function to the below

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

 var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host     : 'xxx',
 user     : 'admin',
 password : 'xxx',
 database : 'xxx',
 port : 3306
});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
 await connection.connect(function(err) {
   if (err) context.fail();
   else context.succeed('Success');
 });

callback(close(sessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled',
 {'contentType': 'PlainText', 'content': `Thank you ${connection.state}`}));
};
```

Comment: Please declare the `exports.handler` as `async` otherwise it will ends up in an error.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I tried adding the async function into it to match your await function but it generated a null response from lambda. My code is as follows : ```exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
 await connection.connect(function(err) {
   if (err) context.fail();
   else context.succeed('Success');
 });

callback(close(sessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled',
 {'contentType': 'PlainText', 'content': `Thank you ${connection.state}`}));
};```

Comment: Interesting, if you add any comments inside of the callback for your connection.connect does it print them in CloudWatch logs?

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you for your response. I made some minor edits to the original code above. Could you please see if that could be a problem. Thank you!